# UITabBar over UIViewController

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UITabBarController with two UIViewController inside.
How to initilaiser UIViewController not to display a portion is below the UITabBar ?

Edit:

**AppDelegate.m:**

```
ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
self.tabController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
[self.tabController setViewControllers:@[viewController] animated:YES];
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabController;
```

**ViewController.m:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view addSubview: [[MyGraphicView alloc] initWithFrame:[self.view bounds]]];
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your question. Can you provide the code you'r using? If I understood it right, you have a layout issue. Can you provide a screenshot if so?

Comment: In addition to providing a screenshot as @Julian asked, how are you setting the `frame` and/or `bounds` of your `UIViewController`?

Answer (score 0):

> How to initilaiser UIViewController not to display a portion is below the UITabBar ?

I think you're mistaking the gloss effect for translucency that's allowing the table to show through the tab bar. Here's an image showing two tabs:

[image: tab bar]

It does *look* like the content view is showing through from under the tab bar, but it's not really showing through -- you're just seeing the glossy effect used to draw the tab items. To illustrate, I'll change the background color of the content to purple:

[image: purple content]

If the content were really showing through the tab bar, you'd see purple showing instead of the white/gray that you can see is there. To see this in your own app, just scroll the table a bit. If the table were really showing through the tab bar, you would be able to read the content of the next cell, including the "9" and the separator line. I'm sure you won't see that, though.